# RAID Battery Backup without Caching

Tags: raid

Is there any point/benefit to having a battery back unit on a raid controller if write caching is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any point/benefit to having a
>   battery back unit on a raid controller
>   if write caching is disabled?

No, the sole purpose of the battery is to retain the information stored in cache in the event of a power failure.